# Run function passed from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to be able to run a function that is passed by name from a data attribute on the HTML side. I've tried the following below.

HTML:

```
<div class="generic-select" data-help-on-shown="genericFunction" >          
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function genericFunction() {
    console.log("generic function called");
}
```

Other Javascript (separate file):

```
//stepEl is correct divider from above
var genFunction = typeof (stepEl.data("helpOnShown")) === "undefined"
                    ? null
                    : stepEl.data("helpOnShown");

//this prints "genericFunction" as expected
console.log("genFunction = " + genFunction);

if (genFunction) {
    genFunction(); //gives error!
}
```

However, this gives me an error. Is there a way to call a function by a string name?

Comment: use evel("funcitonname()");

Answer (score 0):

If the function is "global", it exists as a property of `window`:

```
window[functionname]()
```